# get/set methods and constructors in class diagram

Tags: constructor, setter, getter, class-diagram

recently I was assigned to develop an use case diagram and a class diagram for a conference management system. First I developed use case diagram and then class diagram. In the class diagram I have the following unclear parts:

1. Do we need to show get and set methods for all the private fields in every class. Or we can omit get and set methods, since it is obvious.
2. Do we need to show the constructors in a class? If it is not necessary, what is the reason for not showing them? I have seen lot of class diagrams without the constructors but the reason for that is beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

**Gets and sets** methods are not UML definition. It is just way how to manipulate with attribute values in some programming languages. Pure UML know attribute , its type, name and other properties.

Typical usage of getters and setters in programing is to implement readonly or derived (calculated) attributes.

You do not have to define getters and setters in uml class diagram.

**Constructor:**

You can define constructor operation in class of course. Constructor operation has keyword "create" at the beginning of its name. You can assign behavior definition to constructor as its method to define how to construct instance of class.

See Common Behavion in UML Superstructure.